# After migrating to AndroidX: Cannot instantiate class: androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, androidx

I migrated to AndroidX (using the wizard in Android Studio), and I'm having problems with the share action provider. The wizard changed (among many other things) `app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"` to `app:actionProviderClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider"`, in my `detailactivity.xml` file.

The app compiles fine, and runs fine, too -- so long as I install it on my device over USB. However, if I compile a signed APK, and install that, I get the following runtime error (when starting the detailfragment):

> W/SupportMenuInflater: Cannot instantiate class: androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider

I didn't notice this problem while developing, since I run/test the app on my device through USB. However, when I'm now testing the (signed/minified) APK, the SHARE button does not work. How can I troubleshoot and fix this? For instance, why does it fail on the signed/minified APK fail, while it works fine when installing on same device through USB?

It's hard to tell specifically where (in the code) the warning occurs, since the code in the APK is minified. Perhaps I could create an APK where the code is *not* minified, so I'd get proper references to lines in the source code (in Android Studio LogCat)?

For reference, here is an excerpt from the class where the warning occurs. I'm assuming the warning occurs somewhere here, as this is what's referencing the shareActionProvider?

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // only the share button
    }


    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

        if (mShareActionProvider != null && mImageData != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareImageIntent());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on #android-dev (IRC), and it seems the problem was that the minifier (for some reason) removes the `androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider` class. Turning off minification produced a working APK.

The fix was to update my `proguard-rules.pro` file with a new "keep" line, to prevent it from removing the class. From before, I had a similar rule for the old Android Support Library, so I added the second line below and now it works.

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
```

thanks @melatonina!

Comment: The minifier chooses some "root" classes, and then follows references from those classes outwards to decide what to keep. Since you are referencing the action provider only in an xml file, it can't "see" the dependency.

Comment: But I am importing and using it in the class shown above, in the question..?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Oh, good point. Then my explanation is wrong, and I don't know why proguard was stripping it out.